# Is normal-ordering useful in supersymmetric theories?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry

As far as I know, the most immediate effects of normal-ordering is the elimination of the zero-point energy (and the zero-point background of any conserved charge) and the elimination of tadpoles in perturbation theory.

In SUSY the zero-point background of all charges is zero, and (in the theories I've studied) there are not tadpoles either. So it seems that normal-ordering is essentially effectless. Is this true to all practical purposes, or is there some point where normal-ordering is useful?

Comment: note: I am using *tadpole* in its generalised sense: "... diagrams with a propagator that connects back to its originating vertex are often also referred as tadpoles."

Comment: note 2: perhaps [Apparent failure of SUSY nonrenormalization theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/223842) might be related?

Comment: Your "Tadpole" definition also excludes the one-loop correction to the $\phi^4$-Theory. Is that intended?

Comment: @Neuneck yes. Note that such a diagram is momentum-independent so it can be entirely reabsorbed into the mass counter-term, so it is essentially irrelevant.

Comment: Is your definition of [tadpole diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tadpole_(physics)) the same as self-loop diagrams?

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes. In the math terminology, tadpole = [loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory)).