# Are self-loop diagrams zero if $L_\text{int}$ has a derivative term?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams, interactions, wick-theorem

I was looking at the theory with interaction Lagrangian $L_\text{int}=\phi^3 \cdot \partial_{\mu}\phi$.

I was computing the following self-loop diagram
\begin{equation}
\langle
\phi_x \phi_z^3 \cdot \partial_{\mu}\phi_z \phi_y
\rangle
=3\cdot D_{xz}\partial_{\mu}D_{zz}D_{zy}.
\end{equation}
But since in euclidean signature
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\mu}D_{zz}=\partial_{\mu}\int_p e^{-i(x-x)}\frac{1}{p^2+m^2} =0
\end{equation}
the diagram should vanish.

So is it true to generally conclude that Feynman graphs vanish when the derivative acts upon a self-loop (i.e. propagator evaluated at same spacetime point)?

(Hence also every diagram with a sub-diagram like this?)

Comment: Note that the interaction term is a total spacetime derivative.

Comment: @Qmechanic I can't really follow what you are trying to say. Sorry.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/512810/2451